# R markdown line break within a string (R Studio)

Tags: r, r-markdown, end-of-line

In regular R code I can do the following (when I put pointer at `long_string` and execute:

```
long_string <- 'a
b'
```

So if I have a very long string then I can just hit `Enter` to split it and R Studio will understand.

In R-markdown the above does not work

````
```{r string test, echo = F}

long_string <- 'a
b'

```
````

If I put pointer at `long_string` and execute, I will end up with `+` in console, meaning that R is expecting end of line command.

One solution is to select whole expression (multiple lines) and run it, but I wonder if there are other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

In Markdown, instead of activating the console via `ctrl`+`ENTER` you might want to run the entire Markdown Chunk by pressing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`. Then you'll obtain the result right below the chunk.